# Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error con Mat table en angular 8

Tags: angular, material-design

Actualmente estoy desarrolando sobre angular 8 y quiero crear una tabla que tenga paginacion  pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [”] at column 1 in expression [”[5,] at column 2 in [”[5,] in ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15 ("
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [ERROR ->][pageSizeOptions]=”[5, 10, 25, 100]”></mat-paginator>
</div>"): ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15
Parser Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected character [”] at column 1 in expression [”[5,] at column 2 in [”[5,] in ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15 ("
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [ERROR ->][pageSizeOptions]=”[5, 10, 25, 100]”></mat-paginator>
</div>"): ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [”] at column 1 in expression [”[5,] at column 2 in [”[5,] in ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15 ("
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [ERROR ->][pageSizeOptions]=”[5, 10, 25, 100]”></mat-paginator>
</div>"): ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15
Parser Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected character [”] at column 1 in expression [”[5,] at column 2 in [”[5,] in ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15 ("
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [ERROR ->][pageSizeOptions]=”[5, 10, 25, 100]”></mat-paginator>
</div>"): ng:///AdminModule/AdminComponent.html@36:15
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11143)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25476)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25464)
    at compiler.js:25408
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25408)
    at compiler.js:25321
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25320)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:7187
handleError @ core.js:7239
next @ core.js:31602
schedulerFn @ core.js:27834
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:27796
(anonymous) @ core.js:30931
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:30818
onHandleError @ core.js:30928
handleError @ zone-evergreen.js:363
runGuarded @ zone-evergreen.js:137
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone-evergreen.js:663
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:566
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:272
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:372
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
resolvePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:791
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:707
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ Admin-Admin-module.js:1
```

Código del component.html

```
<style type="text/css">
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Employee Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EmpName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Employee Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EmpName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Color Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Color">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Color </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Color}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Hours Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Hours">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Hours </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.Hours}} </td>      
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]=”[5, 10, 25, 100]”></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Código del component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
import {Admin} from "./Admin";
import {AdminServices} from '../Services/Admin.services'
import {MatTableDataSource,MatPaginator} from '@angular/material';



export interface EmployeeData {
  Id: string;
  EmpName: string; 
  Color: string;
  Hours: number;
}

const FAVORITE_COLORS: string[] = ['gray', 'black', 'navy', 'blue', 'teal', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'olive', 'aqua', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'maroon'];
const EMP_NAMES: string[] = ['Robert', 'Jing Jo', 'Thomas', 'Peter', 'Sam', 'Jack',
  'Charlie', 'Maria', 'Julia', 'Albert', 'Arthur', 'James',
  'Simran', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];


  function getEmployees(id: number): EmployeeData {
  const name =
  EMP_NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (EMP_NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
  EMP_NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (EMP_NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

  return {
    Id: id.toString(),
    EmpName: name,
    Color: FAVORITE_COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (FAVORITE_COLORS.length - 1))],
    Hours: 8
  };
}



@Component({
    selector: 'app-Admin',
    templateUrl: './Admin.component.html',
    providers:[AdminServices]
})


export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator,{static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'EmpName', 'Color', 'Hours'];
dataSourceTable: MatTableDataSource<EmployeeData>;

  emplist: any;

constructor(){
    // Create 100 employees
    this.emplist = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, k) => getEmployees(k + 1));  
    // Assign the data to the data source
    this.dataSourceTable = new MatTableDataSource(this.emplist);

}

    ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSourceTable.paginator = this.paginator;
    }




}
```

código del component.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AdminRoutingModule } from './Admin-routing.module';
import { AdminComponent } from './Admin.component';
import { PageHeaderModule } from '../../shared';
import { MatTableModule } from  '@angular/material';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, AdminRoutingModule, PageHeaderModule, MatTableModule,MatPaginatorModule],
    declarations: [AdminComponent]
})
export class AdminModule {




}
```